# Derivative of $\zeta=\partial_1f ⋅dx_2 ∧ dx_3-\partial_2f ⋅dx_1 ∧ dx_3+\partial_3f ⋅ dx_1 ∧ dx_2 \in \mathcal{A}^2(H)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $H= \mathbb{R}^3$ \ $\{b\}$. Let $f:H \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=-|x-b|^{-1}$, and

$\zeta=\partial_1f ⋅dx_2 ∧ dx_3-\partial_2f ⋅dx_1 ∧ dx_3+\partial_3f ⋅ dx_1 ∧ dx_2 \in \mathcal{A}^2(H)$

I feel a bit stupid for asking this but how do I calculate the derivative of this? I know that the answer should be $0$ but the notation is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Note that $\zeta={}\star{}\mathrm{d}f$ so $\mathrm{d}\zeta=\mathrm{d}\star\mathrm{d}f={}\star\Delta f$ and we know $\Delta f=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 while true, it feels like this exercise is an attempt to illustrate that fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We compute using the exterior derivative.
The expression
$$ \zeta = \partial_1 f \ dx_2\wedge dx_3 - \partial_2 f \ dx_1\wedge dx_3 + \partial_3 f \ dx_1\wedge dx_2 $$

is a differential $2$-form on $H$ of smoothness class $C^1$, because $f$ is a $C^2$ function $H\to \mathbb{R}$.

So we compute
$$
d\zeta = d (\partial_1 f \ dx_2\wedge dx_3) - d(\partial_2 f \ dx_1\wedge dx_3) + d(\partial_3 f \ dx_1\wedge dx_2) \quad (\star)
$$
by linearity of the exterior derivative. Let's simplify the first term in $(\star)$. See that
\begin{align*}
 d (\partial_1 f \ dx_2\wedge dx_3) &= \partial_1\partial_1f \ dx_1\wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3 + \partial_2 \partial_1 f\ dx_2\wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3 + \partial_3 \partial_1 f\ dx_3\wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3 \quad (*) \\
&= \partial_1\partial_1f \ dx_1\wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3
\end{align*}

where the second and third terms in the right hand side of $(*)$ vanish by using the alternating property of the wedge product.
Similarly the second and third terms in $(\star)$ simplify to
$$ -d(\partial_2 f \ dx_1\wedge dx_3) = -\partial_2\partial_2 f\ dx_2\wedge dx_1\wedge dx_3 = \partial_2\partial_2 f\ dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3  $$
and
$$ d(\partial_3 f \ dx_1\wedge dx_2) = \partial_3\partial_3f\  dx_3 \wedge dx_1\wedge dx_2 = \partial_3\partial_3f\  dx_1 \wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3  $$
by using the alternating property of the wedge product.

Therefore we use $(\star)$ to tell us
\begin{align*}
 d\zeta &= \partial_1\partial_1 f\  dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3 + \partial_2\partial_2 f\  dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3 + \partial_3\partial_3 f\  dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3 \\
  &= (\partial_1\partial_1 f + \partial_2\partial_2 f + \partial_3\partial_3 f)\ dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3 \\
  &= \Delta f\  dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3
\end{align*}

where $\Delta f$ denotes the Laplacian of $f$.

I leave it to you the show that $f$ is a *harmonic* function on $H$, i.e. show that $\Delta f(p)=0$ for all points $p\in H$.